# $m$ square-free integer such that $4\vert m-1\implies 2$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$

Tags: ring-theory, euclidean-algorithm, euclidean-domain

Let $m$ square-free integer such that $4\vert m-1$. I need to prove that
$2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$.

What I taught is to use the following theorem:

**LEMMA**: *Let $R$ a Euclidian domain with respect to $\phi$, and $\alpha=\min\{\phi(a):a\in R(\{0\}\bigcup R^{*})\}$, where $R^{*}$ denote the invertible elements of $R$. So the element $b\in R(\{0\}\bigcup R^{*})$ such that $\phi(b)=a$ is irreducible in $R$.*

Well, **IF** $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$ is a Euclidian domain with respect to $\phi(a+b\sqrt{m})=|a^2-mb^2|$, so I can use the Lemma, since $\alpha=4\implies b=2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$.

I just need to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$ is a Euclidian domain.

Is easy to see that $\phi$ is multiplicative, but the Euclidian Algorithm part is confuse to me.

Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}] $ actually a Euclidian domain (supposing $m$ square free and $4\vert m-1)?$

Comment: did you mean $a^2\color{red}-mb^2$?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain), the norm-Euclidean quadratic fields   are $ \mathbb {Q} ({\sqrt {d}}),$ where $d$ takes the values
$−11, −7, −3, −2, −1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 29, 33, 37, 41, 57, 73 $

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, sorry, just typing mistake.

Answer (score -1):

If $4\mid m-1$, then $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$ is not integrally closed and so cannot be an Euclidean domain.

Indeed, if $4\mid m-1$, then the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{m}}{2}]$.

Comment: I didn't learn about integral closure yet, so I didn't understand

Comment: @MateusRocha, equivalently, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$ is not a UFD when $4\mid m-1$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111369/example-demonstrating-that-r-abi-sqrt5-a-b-in-mathbbz-is-not-a-eucli